# How to underline button text (using CSS) when mouse pointer is over the button?

Tags: html, css

I've made a button but being me it isn't good enough and I want it to change it's properties when the mouse pointer hovers over it. I've tried:

```
a:hover #button {
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

as well as:

```
a:hover input {
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-In</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body-color">
<h1 id="heading">Welcome to the Intarnet.</h1>
<hr style="color:#E6B636">
<div id="Sign-In">
<center><legend>Please enter your username and password.</legend></center>
<hr style="color:#E6B636">
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br>
Password: <br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40"><br><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In">
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

-Trey

Comment: you can't insert an <input> or a <button> inside a <a>

Comment: Although it is invalid to put that element inside an `a` tag, you could try `a input:hover`. But seeing your code, you don't even have an `a` tag in your HTML.

Comment: you can just use `input:hover`, do you need the `a` tag?

Comment: no results I'm afraid :(

Comment: after your update: why `a:hover` if you have no link in page?

Comment: I've just started the project and I like to do it methodically

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its as easy as:

```
input[type=submit]:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j5ns/)

You want to target your button (you could do it directly with `#button` or use the above to target all `submit` elements) then apply the underline on the `:hover` selector

Comment: p.s won't let me accept your answer for 10 mins (a stupid thing on here)!